# Write to App Insights from Powershell Running Inside Webjob

Tags: powershell, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobssdk

I'm running a PowerShell script using the process outlined here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2014/01/22/running-powershell-web-jobs-on-azure-websites/

I'm also catching errors within the script and logging them to Application Insights using the method here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-application-insights-in-powershell/

When the code runs, I forced an error by introducing a typo into the script. The exception is caught and the `TrackException()` call happens without issue, but no log entry ever makes it to application insights!
I've tried running the same script locally and it logs just fine.

Example script:

```
$rootPath = ($env:webroot_path)
Add-Type -Path "$rootPath\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"
$appInsightsClient = New-Object Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient
$appInsightsClient.InstrumentationKey = "the-key"


try {
    $lastSuccessDate = Get-Dates "1/1/1900"
} catch {
    [Console]::WriteLine($_.Exception.Message)
    $telemetryException = New-Object "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.ExceptionTelemetry"
    $telemetryException.Exception = $_.Exception
    $appInsightsClient.TrackException($telemetryException)

    Exit 1
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example with more details, without your code and error message we can just guess.

Comment: I added example code that would run in a webjob. Like I said there is no error message. It executes just fine. Thanks.

Comment: if you add `$appInsightsClient.Flush()` after `TrackException($telemtryException)`  does it make it to insights?

Comment: No it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I have never messed with `ApplicationInsights` . According to [this article](https://vnextengineer.azurewebsites.net/powershell-application-insights/) it should work. Sorry I can't be of more help. I would see if using `$appInsightsClient.TrackEvent("Test Event")` would post normally. This would tell you if it is the exception that is causing it or not. If so, you might try it without the `[Console]::WriteLine($_.Exception.Message)`. If not, you might have to add `LoadFile` the dll : `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("<dll path>")` -- in place of `Add-Type`

Comment: OMG! I wrote too soon! It actually worked! It just took a few mins for it to show up in app insights. Thank you so much. Add your answer below and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the exception to update `ApplicationInsights`, you need to add `Flush()` to the `TelemetryClient`

Add:

```
$appInsightsClient.TrackException($TelException)
$appInsightsClient.Flush()
```